# gcc warning volatile double array

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Hi i have a question about the following code fragment writen in true C language

```
    volatile double samp[256];
```

When i trying to compile it gcc gave me a followed warrning:

```
    array 'samp' assumed to have one element
```

My question is that C++ array declaration style is correct in true C?

Comment: That is strange. That's correct syntax, and I get no such warning from my gcc. Can it be that your array dimension is given by a macro instead of a literal constant?

Comment: Could you check in your program if `samp` array is declared elsewhere?

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? (To find out, run `gcc --version`.)

Comment: Can't repro here either.  I have a feeling this isn't your actual code.

Comment: sorry I forgot post that is for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: Is `sizeof(size_t) == 1` there?

Comment: @DanielFischer The ARM architecture isn't *that* crappy :D

Comment: I smell fake code. I suspect the line number in the warning does not match the line number of the excerpt you showed us.

Comment: I think that posting the exactly warning type could be useful, GCC online doc lists warning names not messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language "*assumed to have one element*" is from [Technical Corrigendum 1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc1.htm) to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (C90):

> If at the end of the translation unit containing
>   `int i[];`
>   the array `i` still has incomplete type, the array is assumed to have one element. This element is initialized to zero on program startup.

This indicates that you have declared an array without an array bound:

```
volatile double samp[];
```

You should check all the definitions of `samp`.

Comment: Thanks I am ashamed. You right, always the same "mes in code" Eclipse didn't save my file and i compiled old version...